# Can't remove some simple accents

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove accents from some strings. I only need to replace the following: é, á, í and ó with e, a, i and o.
I've spent at least an hour googling and tried every method I could find, many of them from this site.

I tried the `iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);` method, `preg_replace`, `str_replace`, the Wordpress method and a bunch of others. Either nothing is replaced, or I get a result where `habláis` turns into `habl'ais` or `habl?is`.

I will just list the last method I tried. Please, if someone can give me a method that works, I would so appreciate it. I only need to replace those stupid 4 characters. Going insane here!

This method turns `habláis` into `habl?is`

```
    $newstring = strtr(utf8_decode($string), utf8_decode('áéíó'), 'aeio');
```

Comment: I don't t hink you have UTF8 in the first place, I think you have Windows ISO 1252 that's the reason you're having these problems.

Comment: Solution with `iconv` work fine. http://ideone.com/sypLOR Ensure that your source encoding is utf-8.

Comment: I have the following in my header. Is that not enough to turn on UTF8 encoding? Sorry if this is a stupid beginner question.
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have UTF-8 encoding (else, refer to the comments on your question), I would recommend trying [`str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). This function accepts arrays for the *needle* and the *replacement* which should work perfectly for your needs.

I have not tested this, yet, but something like the following should work:

```
<?php
$aReplacements = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o');
$aNeedles = array('á', 'é', 'í', 'ó');

$string = $_GET['please_replace_this_assignment_with_your_string_source'];

$converted = str_replace($aNeedles, $aReplacements, $string); // Swap to non-accented versions

echo $converted; // Just here for testing. Do what you need to do with this variable.

?>
```